# In-app purchase error with license testing enabled [DF-BA-AH-01]

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases and seems that is working fine. When I try to buy an item, the dialogs appears with the price. However, when I put my email account (or another email without any realtion with the developer account) into the "license testing" list to make a test purchase, the dialog shows this error after login with my Gmail account:

[image: Testing purchase error]

I've read a lot of posts but I've no idea of what can be happening...

I'm using the billing client library:

```
 compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
```

And this is part of the code:

```
private void initBilling(){
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                     BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                          .setSku(CORRECT_SKU)
                          .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS) 
                          .build();
                     int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(NameOfActivity.this, flowParams);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you Set the Sku created in your in App Products as Active in your Subscription In App Products?
I'm Currently working on it. so, if you briefly explain your question my be I can help you.

Comment: Yes, it has been created and activated. The item is being detected in the App, but when I login with my Gmail account to make the purchase the error above commented appears

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while using the reserved test IDs (such as `android.test.purchased`), I was wrongfully trying to purchase a subscription instead of a product.